# softkeyboard doesn't show in landscape mode?

Tags: android

I have to show app in both orientation but when i tap edittext it shows softkeyboard but it works only in portrait mode.

i used code to show softkeyboard

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,
                        InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
```

and code to hide softkeyboard

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(nameEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

when i switch on to landscape it doesn't show softkeyboard 
how can i show softkeyboard in landscape mode.

thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Put this code in manifest and try,

```
<activity name="your actiivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize">
```